# Compare Combinations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, combinations

I need to compare two attributes in a table as a single combination.

Basically I have this table in my database with these attributes and some sample data.

```
Rights => RoleID,SectionID,RightID
      1         2        3
      1         3        5
      1         5        7
      2         3        5
      2         1        6
```

so I want to pass the sectionID and RightID information belonging to a certain roleID as input in my stored procedure and return the ROleID. For example when I pass the combinations (3,5) and (1,6) my stored procedure should return RoleID 2. If there is no exact match with the combinations I pass as my input, it shouldn't return anything.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but you might able to use this or amend as appropriate. The idea is that you put the joined values into temp column then use that as basis for calling the procedure. If that fails you might want to add another column to your table with the joined roleid and sectioned?

CREATE PROCEDURE GETRIGHTS
(
@param varchar(10)
)

AS

SELECT * INTO #RIGHTS FROM TABLENAME 
ALTER TABLE #RIGHTS ADD JOINEDVALUES INT
SELECT #RIGHTS.JOINEDVALUE = (SELECT ROLEID + ',' + SECTIONID FROM TABLENAME WHERE #RIGHTS.JOINEDVALUE = @PARAMS)

Comment: Your procedure is good, but he want 2 when he pass 3, 5 but if you see table 3,5 combo is used twice. so that will return 2 rows.

Comment: I need to compare both sectionID and RightId attributes as a single combination. I should be able to pass values (3,5) and (1,6) to my stored procedure and it should return role id 2. With your suggestion I can pass only one instnce of section id and role id.